# Creating Indexes in JanusGraph with DynamoDB and ElasticSearch as backend

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-dynamodb, janusgraph

I am trying to create the indexes with Elastic Search.

I have below in dynamodb.properties:

```
index.search.backend=elasticsearch
index.search.hostname=10.0.0.55
```

The gremlin server comes up without any exceptions.

I am able to connect to the gremlin server from gremlin console.

```
:remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote.yaml session
:remote console
```

I created below vertices in the graph:

```
gremlin> g.V().properties()
==>vp[name->sandeep]
==>vp[name->uday]
```

I am trying to create the indexes on the property "name" and it is getting stuck in "INSTALLED" state.

```
graph.tx().rollback() //Never create new indexes while a transaction is active
mgmt = graph.openManagement()
name = mgmt.getPropertyKey('name')
mgmt.buildIndex('byNameComposite', Vertex.class).addKey(name).buildCompositeIndex()
mgmt.commit()

//Wait for the index to become available
mgmt.awaitGraphIndexStatus(graph, 'byNameComposite').call()
```

3589249 [gremlin-server-session-1] INFO org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.management.GraphIndexStatusWatcher - Some key(s) on index byNameComposite do not currently have status(es) [REGISTERED]: name=INSTALLED
3589709 [gremlin-server-worker-1] WARN org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.op.AbstractEvalOpProcessor - Script evaluation exceeded the configured threshold for request [RequestMessage{, requestId=40375b29-d180-4732-9816-24870fb1b3b1, op='eval', processor='session', args={gremlin=mgmt.awaitGraphIndexStatus(graph, 'byNameComposite').call(), session=ef0c3a0e-bef0-4a93-bc29-7869c1fd24db, bindings={}, manageTransaction=false, batchSize=64}}]
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Script evaluation exceeded the configured 'scriptEvaluationTimeout' threshold of 30000 ms or evaluation was otherwise cancelled directly for request [mgmt.awaitGraphIndexStatus(graph, 'byNameComposite').call()]

I tried the same thing in my local Janusgraph with ES and Cassandra and was able to use the index.

Please help me out.
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks
Sandeep